# SQL Order By Case When

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a SQL where I want to order by Name. But name has values 'NAME UNKNOWN' OR name of person (i.e. logged in user name).
Is there a way to write ORDER BY in this case so that name of person comes first and then 'NAME UNKNOWN'?

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'NAME UNKNOWN' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, name
```

Comment: Just add the the name still, so it still orders by name. ie. `CASE... , name`

Comment: @SilverFish No worries mate. Please don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write the `order by` clause like this

```
order by case when name = 'NAME UNKNOWN' then 'ZZZ' else name end
```

This way the 'NAME UNKNOWN' names will be counted as 'ZZZ'

Comment: The problem with this approach I think is that you cannot know for sure that there is a value lower than `'ZZZ'`. So it is not "entirely safe".